# NULL value returned when trying to fetch data from solidity smart contract from react js

Tags: solidity, remix, react, database, smart-contract-wallets

I'm trying to make a Student Management System using Ethereum blockchain. I've linked my smart contract (solidity) with react frontend. I try to get the setted value from the smart contract, but this returns "null" in the console. But the smart contract works fine. I'll link my smart contract and the App.js code below. Please help me to solve the issue. As I'm new to the development I'm not much aware of it. Thanks in advance.

Smart contract code

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.9.0;


contract SimpleStorage{
    string name;
    string dept;
    uint phonenumber;
    string addresshome;
    string emailid;
    uint aadhar;
    string ipfshash1;
    string ipfshash2;
    string ipfshash3;
    string ipfshash4;
    constructor() public {
        phonenumber=0;
        aadhar=0;
        
    }
    
    function setname(string memory _name) public {
        name=_name;
    }
    
    function getname() public view returns(string memory){
        return name;
    }
    function setdept(string memory _dept) public {
        dept=_dept;
    }
    function getdept() public view returns(string memory){
        return dept;
    }
    function setphonenumber(uint _phonenumber) public{
        phonenumber=_phonenumber;
    }

    function getphonenumber() public view returns(uint){
        return phonenumber;
    }
    
    function setaddresshome(string memory _addresshome) public {
        addresshome=_addresshome;
    }
    function getaddresshome() public view returns(string memory ){
        return addresshome;
    }
    function setemailid(string memory _emailid) public {
        emailid=_emailid;
    }
    function getemailid() public view returns(string memory){
        return emailid;
    }
    
    function setaadhar(uint _aadhar) public {
        aadhar=_aadhar;
    }
    function getaadhar() public view returns(uint){
        return aadhar;
    }
}
```

App.js code

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Web3 from 'web3';
import { simpleStorageAbi } from './abi/abis';
import './App.css';
const web3 = new Web3(Web3.givenProvider);
// contract address is provided by Truffle migration
const contractAddr = '0x262E2078217937978cccd3a08681AdD77D5DdFE3';
const SimpleContract = new web3.eth.Contract(simpleStorageAbi, contractAddr);
function App() {
  const [name, setName] = useState();
  const [getName, setGetName] = useState();

  const [dept, setDept] = useState();
  const [getDept, setGetDept] = useState();

  const [phonenumber, setPhonenumber] = useState();
  const [getPhonenumber, setGetPhonenumber] = useState();

  const [homeaddress, setHomeaddress] = useState();
  const [getHomeaddress, setGetHomeaddress] = useState();

  const [emailid, setEmailid] = useState();
  const [getEmailid, setGetEmailid] = useState();

  const [aadhar, setAadhar] = useState();
  const [getAadhar, setGetAadhar] = useState();



  const handleNameSet = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();    
    const accounts = await window.ethereum.enable();
    const account = accounts[0];
    const gas = await SimpleContract.methods.setname(name).estimateGas();
    const result = await SimpleContract.methods.setname(name).send({
      from: account,
      gas 
    })
    console.log(result);
  }

  const handleNameGet = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const result = await SimpleContract.methods.getname().call();
    setGetName(result);
    console.log(result);
  }

  const handleDeptSet = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();    
    const accounts = await window.ethereum.enable();
    const account = accounts[0];
    const gas = await SimpleContract.methods.setdept(dept).estimateGas();
    const result = await SimpleContract.methods.setdept(dept).send({
      from: account,
      gas 
    })
    console.log(result);
  }

  const handleDeptGet = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const result = await SimpleContract.methods.getdept().call();
    setGetDept(result);
    console.log(result);
  }


  const handlePhonenumberSet = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();    
    const accounts = await window.ethereum.enable();
    const account = accounts[0];
    const gas = await SimpleContract.methods.setphonenumber(name).estimateGas();
    const result = await SimpleContract.methods.setphonenumber(name).send({
      from: account,
      gas 
    })
    console.log(result);
  }

  const handlePhonenumberGet = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const result = await SimpleContract.methods.getphonenumber().call();
    setGetPhonenumber(result);
    console.log(result);
  }
  

  const handleHomeaddressSet = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();    
    const accounts = await window.ethereum.enable();
    const account = accounts[0];
    const gas = await SimpleContract.methods.setaddresshome(name).estimateGas();
    const result = await SimpleContract.methods.setaddresshome(name).send({
      from: account,
      gas 
    })
    console.log(result);
  }

  const handleHomeaddressGet = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const result = await SimpleContract.methods.getaddresshome().call();
    setGetHomeaddress(result);
    console.log(result);
  }

  const handleEmailidSet = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();    
    const accounts = await window.ethereum.enable();
    const account = accounts[0];
    const gas = await SimpleContract.methods.setemailid(name).estimateGas();
    const result = await SimpleContract.methods.setemailid(name).send({
      from: account,
      gas 
    })
    console.log(result);
  }

  const handleEmailidGet = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const result = await SimpleContract.methods.getemailid().call();
    setGetEmailid(result);
    console.log(result);
  }

  const handleAadharSet = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();    
    const accounts = await window.ethereum.enable();
    const account = accounts[0];
    const gas = await SimpleContract.methods.setaadhar(name).estimateGas();
    const result = await SimpleContract.methods.setaadhar(name).send({
      from: account,
      gas 
    })
    console.log(result);
  }

  const handleAadharGet = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const result = await SimpleContract.methods.getaadhar().call();
    setGetAadhar(result);
    console.log(result);
  }

return (
  <div className="App">
    <header className="App-header">
      <h1> Student Details </h1>
    </header>
    <div className="wrapper">
      <form className= "Form" onSubmit={handleNameSet}>
        <label>
          <h3 style={{textAlign:"left",marginBottom:"0.5px",fontFamily:"unset"}}>NAME:</h3>
          <input className="Form"
            type="text"
            name="name"
            value={name}
            onChange={ e => setName(e.target.value) } />
        </label>
        <input className="body" type="submit" value="Set it" />
        <button
        className="body"
        onClick={handleNameGet}
        type="button" > 
        Get it
      </button>
      { getName }
      </form>


      <form className= "Form" onSubmit={handleDeptSet}>
      <label>
          <h3 style={{textAlign:"left",marginBottom:"0.5px",fontFamily:"unset"}}>DEPARTMENT:</h3>
          <input className="Form"
            type="text"
            name="dept"
            value={dept}
            onChange={ e => setDept(e.target.value) } />
        </label>
        <input className="body" type="submit" value="Set it" />
        <button
        className="body"
        onClick={handleDeptGet}
        type="button" > 
        Get it 
      </button>
      { getDept }
       </form>

       <form className= "Form" onSubmit={handlePhonenumberSet}>
      <label>
          <h3 style={{textAlign:"left",marginBottom:"0.5px",fontFamily:"unset"}}>PHONE NUMBER:</h3>
          <input className="Form"
            type="text"
            name="dept"
            value={phonenumber}
            onChange={ e => setPhonenumber(e.target.value) } />
        </label>
        <input className="body" type="submit" value="Set it" />
        <button
        className="body"
        onClick={handlePhonenumberGet}
        type="button" > 
        Get it 
      </button>
      { getPhonenumber }
       </form>


       <form className= "Form" onSubmit={handleHomeaddressSet}>
        <label>
          <h3 style={{textAlign:"left",marginBottom:"0.5px",fontFamily:"unset"}}>ADDRESS:</h3>
          <input className="Form"
            type="text"
            name="name"
            value={homeaddress}
            onChange={ e => setHomeaddress(e.target.value) } />
        </label>
        <input className="body" type="submit" value="Set it" />
        <button
        className="body"
        onClick={handleHomeaddressGet}
        type="button" > 
        Get it
      </button>
      { getHomeaddress }
      </form>

      <form className= "Form" onSubmit={handleEmailidSet}>
        <label>
          <h3 style={{textAlign:"left",marginBottom:"0.5px",fontFamily:"unset"}}>EMAIL ID:</h3>
          <input className="Form"
            type="text"
            name="name"
            value={emailid}
            onChange={ e => setEmailid(e.target.value) } />
        </label>
        <input className="body" type="submit" value="Set it" />
        <button
        className="body"
        onClick={handleEmailidGet}
        type="button" > 
        Get it
      </button>
      { getEmailid }
      </form>

      <form className= "Form" onSubmit={handleAadharSet}>
        <label>
          <h3 style={{textAlign:"left",marginBottom:"0.5px",fontFamily:"unset"}}>AADHAR NO.:</h3>
          <input className="Form"
            type="text"
            name="name"
            value={aadhar}
            onChange={ e => setAadhar(e.target.value) } />
        </label>
        <input className="body" type="submit" value="Set it" />
        <button
        className="body"
        onClick={handleAadharGet}
        type="button" > 
        Get it
      </button>
      { getAadhar }
      </form>

      <br/>
      </div>
      
      <button className="files" type="button" >Add files..</button>

  </div>  
);
};
export default App;
```

Comment: What's the exact error message? Where were the contracts deploy? ganache, rinkeby. The connection to web3 look strange if you are connecting to Metamask.

Comment: I'm using truffle to deploy the contracts. I tried using it with another account,it worked but after that it didn't work properly

Comment: If data returns null perhaps the transaction failed and it didn't store changes. If you're using ganache they have an explorer that will show the transaction. Check if the gas is high enough, for testing use a hardcoded number instead of using estimateGas, "2000000" should be enough for setters. I suggest to emit an event when modifying a field, so that you can check the transaction receipt for triggered events.